# Is there an expanding rectangular space filling curve 'growing' around a point in space?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Do there exist 'expanding' 3D rectangular space filling curves?

(The actual problem:
I'm writing a block-based voxel engine where chunks should be loaded depending on their distance from the player. I have an upper limit on how many chunks can be loaded in a single frame. Using a SFC will allow to store only the last processed chunk's position instead of a queue for flood fill.)

Comment: So, your player will be stationary? If not, then think what happens when the player moves. Think of the known volume as a sphere centered around the user. When the player moves, the sphere moves. Your space-filling curve would also (have to!) move to this new position. Which breaks your idea: the unknown part of the volume, especially after a few movements, will be more like clusters of unloaded voxels, with some already loaded voxels in between.

Comment: If I may, I'd suggest you consider implementing the voxel queue as a binary min-heap, with the key being derived mostly from the distance, or perhaps distance adjusted by the current speed and direction (to make sure forward voxels are loaded first). The implementation of such a min-heap is interesting in itself, especially because you'll want to modify the keys for each queued voxel as the player moves. Wikipedia [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) and [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) are useful. You'd want to store the heap in an array, too.

Comment: There's a counter storing how many chunks have been created in the visible 'bubble' around the player. When the player moves and num_created_chunks < num_total_chunks, I restart flood fill with the new position. If all chunks in the visible region are filled, it just wraps around ('rolling' array with toroidal ('modulo') addressing, clipmap). The flood fill is required only after a new world is created or the player teleports too far. Min-heap is a spiffy idea, but I'd like to avoid allocating an array or performing ugly checks in 6 directions for flood fill.